# making Alchemy and UnitTest++ work together

Tags: flash, alchemy, unittest++

I'm using [Adobe Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) in a project that uses [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/).  The unit tests run as part of the build process.

It turns out that UnitTest++ depends on a feature of C++ that [isn't implemented in Alchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169892/globals-broken-with-alchemy), namely instantiating static classes and/or calling functions to initialize global vars.

The great thing about UnitTest++ is that you don't have to remember to add your tests to the list of tests to run.  It happens automatically using some macro-magic to create test-case classes and add them to a global list of tests.  So this:

```
TEST(MyTest) {
    CHECK(doSomething());
}
```

becomes this:

```
class TestMyTest : public UnitTest::Test {
   ...
} testMyTestInstance;

UnitTest::ListAdder adderMyTest(UnitTest::Test::GetTestList(), &testMyTestInstance);
```

where the constructor for `ListAdder` adds `testMyTestInstance` to the global list of tests.

The problem is that because of the Alchemy bug, the `ListAdder` constructor never runs, so the list of tests is always empty.

To prove that the `ListAdder` constructor is never getting called, you can instrument it to crash when it gets called:

```
ListAdder::ListAdder(TestList& list, Test* test) {
    int *p= (int*)INT_MAX;   // NULL won't crash alchemy (!)
    *p= 0;                   // boom
    list.Add(test);
}
```

This will crash when compiled natively, but won't when compiled with Alchemy.

A less drastic way to see it is to just add a printf:

```
ListAdder::ListAdder(TestList& list, Test* test) {
    printf("ListAdder %s \n", test->m_details.testName);
    list.Add(test);
}
```

When compiled natively, you'll see "ListAdder ..." for each test, but when compiled under Alchemy it won't print anything.

My question is: how can I modify UnitTest++ so that the tests will run?  The workarounds [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169892/globals-broken-with-alchemy) don't seem to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some doing, but I figured it out.  The trick is that static initializer *functions* will work, e.g.,

```
int someFunc() {
    return 42;
}
int someVal= someFunc();
```

as long as they don't call any constructors or use new/malloc or use printf.  (It took me a while to realize that Gunslinger47 was right about the printfs screwing things up.)

The fact that static initializer functions work is just enough to let us get UnitTest++ working.  What we do is use a variation of the "Pointers" workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169892/globals-broken-with-alchemy/4171120#4171120):

- Instead of being allocated statically, each test class has an allocator function
- A pointer to each allocator function is added to a list of function pointers
- In main, this list of function pointers is then iterated through and each function called.

The gritty details are below:

(1) In TestMacros.h, change the TEST_EX macro to use a static initializer function rather than a constructor:

```
#define TEST_EX(Name, List)                                                \
    class Test##Name : public UnitTest::Test                               \
    {                                                                      \
    public:                                                                \
        Test##Name() : Test(#Name, UnitTestSuite::GetSuiteName(), __FILE__, __LINE__) {}  \
    private:                                                               \
        virtual void RunImpl() const;                                      \
    };                                                                     \
                                                                           \
    void create_test##Name##Instance() {                                   \
        Test##Name *test##Name##Instance= new Test##Name();                \
        UnitTest::ListAdder adder##Name (List(), test##Name##Instance);    \
    }                                                                      \
                                                                           \
    UnitTest::test_creator_func_t fp_create_test##Name##Instance=          \
                    UnitTest::addTestCreator(create_test##Name##Instance); \
                                                                           \
    void Test##Name::RunImpl() const


#define TEST(Name) TEST_EX(Name, UnitTest::Test::GetTestList)
```

(2) Change TEST_FIXTURE_EX in a similar manner as TEST_EX.  I'll spare you the verbosity.

(3) At the bottom of TestList.cpp, add the functions that the TEST_EX/TEST_FIXTURE_EX macros call:

```
#if !defined(MAX_TEST_CREATORS)
#define MAX_TEST_CREATORS 1024
#endif

const size_t max_test_creators= MAX_TEST_CREATORS;
size_t num_test_creators= 0;

// This list unfortunately must be static-- if we were to 
// dynamically allocate it, then alchemy would break.
// If it winds up not being big enough, then just inject
// a bigger definition for MAX_TEST_CREATORS 
test_creator_func_t test_creator_list[max_test_creators]= {NULL};   

test_creator_func_t addTestCreator(test_creator_func_t fp) {
    int idx= num_test_creators;

    num_test_creators++;    
    if (num_test_creators > max_test_creators) {
        throw "test creator overflow";
    }

    test_creator_list[idx]= fp;
    return fp;
}

void initializeAllTests() {
    for (size_t idx= 0; idx < num_test_creators; idx++) {
        test_creator_list[idx]();
    }
}
```

and of course add their prototypes to TestList.h:

```
typedef void (*test_creator_func_t)();
test_creator_func_t addTestCreator(test_creator_func_t fp);
void initializeAllTests();
```

(4) Finally, in your unit test runner, you must call initializeAllTests:

```
UnitTest::initializeAllTests();
return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
```

But that's not all!  There are a few other tidbits that need to be done before it'll work:

(1) Make sure UNITTEST_USE_CUSTOM_STREAMS is defined in Config.h:

```
// by default, MemoryOutStream is implemented in terms of std::ostringstream, which can be expensive.
// uncomment this line to use the custom MemoryOutStream (no deps on std::ostringstream).

#define UNITTEST_USE_CUSTOM_STREAMS
```

The reason for this is that if its not defined, MemoryOutStream.h will `#include <sstream>`, which will break static initialization (I suspect that it does some kind of global constructor or something).

(2) In SignalTranslator.h, make sure that the UNITTEST_THROW_SIGNALS macro is a noop.  I do this by injecting a `-D__ALCHEMY__` into my builds and checking for it:

```
#if defined(__ALCHEMY__)
#define UNITTEST_THROW_SIGNALS
#else
#define UNITTEST_THROW_SIGNALS \
    UnitTest::SignalTranslator sig; \
    if (UNITTEST_EXTENSION sigsetjmp(*UnitTest::SignalTranslator::s_jumpTarget, 1) != 0) \
        throw ("Unhandled system exception"); 
#endif
```

If this isn't done, the sigsetjmp call will fail at runtime.